# "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column Staff.id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "Staff"."id", "Staff"."user_id", "Staff"."department"...."

Tags: django, populate

I have created a custom User model and have two models "Staff" and "Patient" having OneToOne relationship with my custom User model. I have successfully migrate but the error occurs when executing the second line of code

```
doc = User.objects.create_user(email='jlennon@beatles.com',password='glassdoor',user_type=1)
s_doc = Staff.objects.get_or_create(user=doc)
```

, I get this ERROR:
"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column Staff.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "Staff"."id", "Staff"."user_id", "Staff"."department"..."

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):

    #use email as authentication
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
      (1, 'doctor'),
      (2, 'labPeople'),
      (3, 'receptionist'),
      (4, 'patient'),
      (5, 'admin'),
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
  # class Meta:
  #       db_table = 'auth_user'

class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff')
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    tel_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='department', blank=True, null=True)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey('Hospital', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='hospital', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'Staff'

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='patient')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sex = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    tel_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    nin = models.AutoField(db_column='NIN', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'Patient'
```

managers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
import django



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    use_in_migrations = True
    def _create_user(self, email, user_type, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        django.setup()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_type=user_type, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, user_type, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if user_type in set([1,2,3,5]):
            is_staff = True
        return self._create_user(email, user_type, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_type, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(email, user_type, password, **extra_fields)
```

The Traceback is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_health.py", line 90, in <module>
    populate()
  File "populate_health.py", line 26, in populate
    s_doc = Staff.objects.get_or_create(user=doc)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 538, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column Staff.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "Staff"."id", "Staff"."user_id", "Staff"."department"...
```

I first got this error when I did not define id for Staff since django just does it automatically. But I just added it to try and the result is the same. I also tried with creating a Patient object, and it would result in the same error.

I have been stuck on this for more than one week and only found some other similar problems happen while migrating which is not the same. How is this happening?

Comment: this is a typical error if you haven't created or updated your models in the DB via `manage.py makemigrations`, `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: @monkut I have done those two commands several times. Cuz at first I was thinking it might be my db problem, so I deleted my whole db by `manage.py flush` and deleted all my migration files. Then I redo the whole process again by `makemigrations` and `migrate`. This error stays there.

Comment: Your db may be out of sync, try dropping the db and re-creating then running `migrate`.

Comment: @monkut I just found that I copied the wrong error message. I just edited it. I have tried dropping the db by doing DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE in the PostgreSQL, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Easy This error is bought by as a result of having multiple values of the "id" since you have a primary key in your table and django has also provided an automatic value for your "id".Drop your current database using "DROP [IF EXISTS]dbname;" then create the database again with the same name and then make the migrations again using "python manage.py makemigrations" then migrate using "python manage.py migrate" and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error but i was able to fix it by erasing all the files but init.py on each application's migration folder, then you can apply makemigrations and migrate. That solve it for me.
edit after: when we tried to tie the user model to the extended model Appuser we encounter an error and it was that the previous coumns made with migrations where not altered when we migrate the new model, for this we erase columns that were not listed in the new model.